# How do I shorten my code instead of writing the same repetitive commands? (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, performance, discord.py

While coding my discord bot, I decided to make commands that would send images from a folder of ~50 images.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

d = 'reactions/'

async def send_reaction(ctx, file):
    f = discord.File(d+file)
    await ctx.send(file=f)

class memes(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot=bot

    @commands.command()
    async def a(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'a.mp4')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def drugged(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'amehypno.png')

    @commands.command()
    async def ameshame(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'ameshame.jpg')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def amestfu(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'amestfu.jpg')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def angryshuba(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'angry.png')
    
    @commands.command()
    async def aproveshuba(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'aprove.png')

    @commands.command()
    async def aquawhat(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'aquawhat.png')

    @commands.command()
    async def cringe(self, ctx):
        await send_reaction(ctx, 'bear cringe.jpg')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(memes(bot))
```

I was planning on doing more, but I quickly realized that I would have to make 40+ commands that were essentially the same thing. How can I shorten my code?

Comment: Do you really want to have one command for one picture? Why don't you make a meme command and choose a random picture out of the folder?

Comment: Sorry if my code was a bit misleading, they aren't really memes, but reaction images. So, if I just picked a random image out of the folder that wouldn't actually be useful.

Comment: can’t you just make one function that takes in the desired reaction? then you have a mapping which maps reactions —> images.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but how is that different than what I'm doing now? The name of the command tells what image they want to send and then the bot gets the related image and sends it.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following solution:
*I couldn't test it, because I don't do Discord bots. So beware of bugs :D*

First create a dict with the command as key and image name as value.

```py
command_image_dict = {
    "drugged": "amehypno.png",
    "ameshame": "ameshame.jpg"
}
```

Then create a general function that answers with an image according to the name of the command. (This is not an actual command but a helper function.)

```
async def memefunction(self, ctx):
    try:
        await send_meme(ctx, command_image_dict[ctx.command])
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Lastly we create a function for each key in the dict by using `setattr`. This creates a new function with the desired name and assigns it the functionality of `memefunction`. Because of the decorator `@commands.command` we need to wrap the `memefunction` as `commands.command(memefunction)`

```
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    for key in command_image_dict:
        setattr(self, key, commands.command(memefunction))
```

This (at least in theory becaus no testing :D) should result in 40+ functions/commands.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! I am unfamiliar with `setattr` so I apologize for my mistakes. It says that `this` is not defined. Should I replace it with something?

Comment: My bad, it's `self` not `this`.

Comment: The command is not being found. Heres my code, can you make sure im doing everything correctly? [code](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/733343799690133606/830882478532460559/unknown.png)

Comment: Looks fine to me. But a I said, I wasn't able to test it, so i can't tell you why it is not working. Hope this helps as a starting-point. Otherwise use a function with the reation as  argument like @gold_cy proposed.